# add save for each row inaddition to double click edit behaviour in editable datagrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui, editablegrid

I am using editable datagrid (https://www.jeasyui.com/extension/edatagrid.php) in which I have used double click editable and it is working fine but I want an 'edit' button for each row when user clicks on 'edit' then 'save|cancel' should be displayed after click on 'save' validation should happen before saving that particular row. **row Validation and row is getting updated fine when I edit it using double click but I want to update row with 'edit' button for each row now.** I have googled for solution but did not find any useful solution.

```
<table id="my_table_edit_id" title='Editable DataGrid' singleSelect="true" style="width:100%; height:500px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th field="channel_name" width="100" editor="{type:'textbox'}">Channel Name</th>
        <th field="channel_category_id" width="100" editor="{type:'combobox',
            options:{
                valueField:'value',
                textField:'text',
                data:categorySelectOptions,
                loadFilter:loadFilter,
                formatter:formatter,
                onLoadSuccess:onLoadSuccess
            }
        }" formatter="getCategoryText" >Category</th>
        <th field="is_pay_channel" width="100" align="right" editor="{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'is_pay_channel',
                    textField:'channel_type',
                    data:payorFTA,
                    required:true,
                    onLoadSuccess:function(rows){
                        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                            var row = rows[i];
                            if (row.selected){
                                $(this).combobox('setValue', row.is_pay_channel);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }" formatter='getChannelType'>Pay/FTA</th>
        <th field="price" width="100" align="right" editor="numberbox">Price</th>
        <th field="carriage_price" width="150" editor="numberbox">Carriage Fee</th>
        <th field="is_hd" width="150" formatter='getHDChannelStatus' editor="{type:'checkbox',
            options:{on: '1',
                off: '0'
            }}">Is HD Channel</th>
        <th field="is_mandatory" width="150" formatter='getMandatoryStatus' editor="{type:'checkbox',
            options:{on: '1',
                off: '0'
            }}">Is Mandatory</th>
        <th field="language_id" width="150" editor="{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'language_id',
                    textField:'language',
                    data:languages,
                    onLoadSuccess:function(rows){
                        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                            var row = rows[i];
                            if (row.selected){
                                $(this).combobox('setValue', row.language_id);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }" formatter="getLanguageText">Language</th>
        <th field="channel_number" width="150" editor="numberbox">Ch.Number</th>
        <!--<th field='action' title='Action' width="80" align='center' formatter='getActionItems'>Action</th>-->
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
$(function(){
        $('#my_table_edit_id').edatagrid({
            idField:'itemid',
            iconCls:'icon-edit',
            url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Controller_Name/method_for_list',
            updateUrl: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Ajax/update_method',
            onBeforeSave:function(index,row){
                 // All Validations goes here submit if everything fine
                --------------------
            },
            onSuccess:function(index,row){
              if(row.hasOwnProperty('msg') && row.msg!==''){
                    alertify.alert(row.msg);
              }else{
                    alertify.alert('Record Updated successfully');
              }
            },
            onError:function(index,row){
                if(row.hasOwnProperty('msg') && row.msg!==''){
                    alertify.alert(row.msg);
                }else{
                    alertify.alert('There is some problem.Please try again later');
                }
            }
       });
});
```

**What I have tried is:**
I have searched and found one solution [here](https://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid12.php) but it is not working. In the solution they said that we can achieve it using normal 'datagrid' so I have changed to normal datagrid and added 'action' item 'edit' then 'update | cancel'. When I click on 'edit' then displaying 'update | cancel' buttons when I edit and click on 'update' button then the update is not working data is not getting updated. **I am confused of 'updateUrl' not mentioned/using in the normal datagrid then how and where the row is getting submitted to?**

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table_id" title='Editable DataGrid' style="width:100%; height:500px;">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th field="channel_name" width="100" editor="{type:'textbox'}">Channel Name</th>
        <th field="channel_category_id" width="100" editor="{type:'combobox',
            options:{
                valueField:'value',
                textField:'text',
                data:categorySelectOptions,
                loadFilter:loadFilter,
                formatter:formatter,
                onLoadSuccess:onLoadSuccess
            }
        }" formatter="getCategoryText" >Category</th>
        <th field="is_pay_channel" width="100" align="right" editor="{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'is_pay_channel',
                    textField:'channel_type',
                    data:payorFTA,
                    required:true,
                    onLoadSuccess:function(rows){
                        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                            var row = rows[i];
                            if (row.selected){
                                $(this).combobox('setValue', row.is_pay_channel);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }" formatter='getChannelType'>Pay/FTA</th>
        <th field="price" width="100" align="right" editor="numberbox">Price</th>
        <th field="carriage_price" width="150" editor="numberbox">Carriage Fee</th>
        <th field="is_hd" width="150" formatter='getHDChannelStatus' editor="{type:'checkbox',
            options:{on: '1',
                off: '0'
            }}">Is HD Channel</th>
        <th field="is_mandatory" width="150" formatter='getMandatoryStatus' editor="{type:'checkbox',
            options:{on: '1',
                off: '0'
            }}">Is Mandatory</th>
        <th field="language_id" width="150" editor="{
                type:'combobox',
                options:{
                    valueField:'language_id',
                    textField:'language',
                    data:languages,
                    onLoadSuccess:function(rows){
                        for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                            var row = rows[i];
                            if (row.selected){
                                $(this).combobox('setValue', row.language_id);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }" formatter="getLanguageText">Language</th>
        <th field="channel_number" width="150" editor="numberbox">Ch.Number</th>
        <th field='action' title='Action' width="90" align='center' formatter='getActionItems'>Action</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

**javascript:**

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#table_id').datagrid({
    idField:'itemid',
    iconCls:'icon-edit',
    url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Controller_Name/method_for_list',
    updateUrl: '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/Ajax/update_action_new',
    onEndEdit:function(index,row){
        // validation goes here, submit if everything works fine
        var variable_1 = "19.00";
        var variable_2 = "1";

        if(parseFloat(variable_1) && variable_2==1){
           var message = "Note: M.R.P of channel is greater than Rs."+variable_1+", it should be created as some_type Package.";
           alertify.confirm( message, function (e) {
             if(e){
               var onBeforeSave = opts.onBeforeSave;
               opts.onBeforeSave = function(){};
               dg.datagrid('updateRow');  // Issue is coming with this line
               opts.onBeforeSave = onBeforeSave;
               // ajaxfunction(channel_id);
             }else{
               $('#table_id').datagrid('cancelEdit');
             }
           });
          return false;
        }
    },
    /*updateRow:function(index,row){
        index: index,
        row.input_field1 = $(ed.target).combobox('getText');
        row.input_field2 = $(ed.target).combobox('getText');
        ------------------------
    },*/
    onBeforeEdit:function(index,row){
        row.editing = true;
        $(this).datagrid('refreshRow', index);
    },
    onAfterEdit:function(index,row){
        row.editing = false;
        $(this).datagrid('refreshRow', index);
    },
    onCancelEdit:function(index,row){
        row.editing = false;
        $(this).datagrid('refreshRow', index);
    },
    onSuccess:function(index,row){
        // console.log("onSuccess");
        // console.log('row',row);
        // console.log('index',index);
        if(row.hasOwnProperty('msg') && row.msg!==''){
            alertify.alert(row.msg);
        }else{
            alertify.alert('Record Updated successfully');
        }
        // console.log(row.msg);
    },
    onError:function(index,row){
        // console.log("onError");
        // console.log('row',row);
        if(row.hasOwnProperty('msg') && row.msg!==''){
            alertify.alert(row.msg);
        }else{
            alertify.alert('There is some problem.Please try again later');
        }
    }
 });
});
function getActionItems(value,row,index){
  // console.log('came to getActionItems',row);
  if (row.editing){
      var s = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="saverow(this)">Save</a> ';
      var c = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="cancelrow(this)">Cancel</a>';
      return s+c;
   } else {
      var e = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="editrow(this)">Edit</a> ';
      // var d = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="deleterow(this)"><i class="fas fa-trash text-danger mr-1"></i></a>';
      return e;
   }
}
function getRowIndex(target){
   var tr = $(target).closest('tr.datagrid-row');
   return parseInt(tr.attr('datagrid-row-index'));
}
function editrow(target){
   $('#table_id').datagrid('beginEdit', getRowIndex(target));
}
function saverow(target){
   $('#table_id').datagrid('endEdit', getRowIndex(target));
}
function cancelrow(target){
   $('#table_id').datagrid('cancelEdit', getRowIndex(target));
}
</script>
```

**I am getting issue in the console as "jquery.easyui.min.js:11739 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined"**

Any help, Please guide me in right direction. thanks.